# Passing ArrayList to separate class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a code that reads from an `SQL` Database and saves each column of information into an `ArrayList`.  I need to pass each `ArrayList` into a separate class where I can store the lists as single pieces of information (IE: Information in the first part of `ArrayList1` goes with information in the first part of `ArrayList2` etc...) and then sort them.  I don't know how to pass that information to another class though.  This is a section of my main method that stores the information into a list.  I need this information passed to a separate class called `List.java`:

```
String SelectStatement1 = "SELECT InvoiceID FROM Invoice;";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(SelectStatement1);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()){
        count++;
    }
    ps.close();
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(SelectStatement1);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ArrayList<String> InvoiceIDList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String InvoiceID = null;
    int p = 0;
    while (p < count){
        rs.next();
        InvoiceID = rs.getString("InvoiceID");
        InvoiceIDList.add(InvoiceID);
        p++;
    }
    ps.close();
    p = 0;
```

Edit: This is only a section of my code, I already have the code open and close the connections, I only need information on how to pass the ArrayList to another class for sorting.

Comment: Simply create a method in the other class, "List", that accepts an arrayList object as the parameter, then parse through the data as required.

Comment: You should probably name *your* class something other than `List`, and it would need a method with a `List<String>` parameter in it's signature.

Comment: A way out is to create a method and use a for loop, but I cant say its the most efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a method in your other class like this:

```
public void receiveList (ArrayList<String> invoiceIDList) {
    // Do something with invoiceIDList data
}
```

It may not be a bad idea to create a *constructor* in your "List" class, that accepts the ArrayList and creates the class instance with the required data

Also, **please** change the name of that class!! It will be confusing to others who read your code, as you are passing an ArrayList already!

**EDIT:**

You could also have your class *implement* the List interface, which would make things a lot easier for you, because you can insert data into your class based on the position of the data in the ArrayList.

```
public class yourClass implements List<String> {
     // Your class methods and variables...
}
```

If you wanted to expand on this to allow more than just Strings, you can change to: `List<T>`, this would give you a more generic approach.

Comment: Consider suggesting coding to the interface, i.e. accepting `List<String>`

Comment: @VincentvanDriel No problem, glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 5):

First, I suggest you perform a `SELECT COUNT()` instead of iterating your rows in your first query. Then remember to `close()` both the `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`. Finally, I would suggest you program to the `List<String>` interface. Putting it all together like,

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
```

Connect to your database and initialize `conn`.

```
int count = 0;
try {
    String query1 = "SELECT COUNT(InvoiceID) FROM Invoice;";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        count = rs.getInt(1);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    try {
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

The above block of code is necessary to `close()` both `rs` and `ps` in the correct order with [the `finally` Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

```
List<String> invoiceIdList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    String query2 = "SELECT InvoiceID FROM Invoice;";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query2);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        invoiceIdList.add(rs.getString("InvoiceID"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally { // <-- it's identical to the finally block above.
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    try {
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
// now you can pass invoiceIdList elsewhere...
if (!invoiceIdList.isEmpty()) {
    doSomething(invoiceIdList);
}
```

Comment: so amazing giving the code with small explanation can lead to reputations.I can not understand **how this code with that explanation can be helpful to the novice op ?!!!!**

Comment: @EvanBechtol It can be cleaned up a lot with something like [this](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Comment: There was no requirement for Java 1.6 - so why not use 1.7 try-with-resources, where all of this becomes sooooo simple and clean ?